# Sklearn Bagging SVM Always Returning Same Prediction

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, ensemble-learning, svc

I'm extracting HSV and LBP histograms from an image and feeding them to a Sklearn Bagging classifier which uses SVC as base estimator for gender detection. I've created a csv file with those histograms saved as vectors in a row. Trained the model on the %80 of this dataset, got 0.92 accuracy in the test dataset. But when I try to run the model in some other python code, the classifier always returning the same output.

I've tried loading the model back to a jupyter notebook and tested with the same dataset to see if there is problem with the save/load processes. Checked the real-time-extracted features and saw they're all different.

Functions to extract mentioned features and make predicitons, (feature_extractor function is the same function that used to create dataset for training):

```py
from skimage import feature
import image_slicer as slicah
import cv2
import numpy as np
import joblib

gender_classifier = joblib.load('models/bagging92.sav')

NumberOfGrids = 16
numPoints = 11## Parameters for LBP
radius = 2

hue_bins = 24
swh_hist = np.zeros(hue_bins)
bin_edges = np.linspace(0,360,hue_bins)  # Calculate bin edges

slope = hue_bins / (bin_edges[-1] + 0.01)  ## Interpolates hue values in degrees to bin labels when multiplied


def feature_extractor(image):
    grids_PIL = slicah.slice_from_array(image, NumberOfGrids, save=False) ## Split image into grids
    feature_vect, blockFeatures, hsv_feature_vect = [], [], []
    w, h, _ = np.shape(grids_PIL[0].image) # Drop the rgb channel
    norm_factor = w * h

    for grid in grids_PIL:  ## Loop through grids
        temp_img = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(grid.image, dtype=np.uint8),
                                cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)  ## Convert PIL image object to np array
        hsv_img = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(grid.image), cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV) ## Convert to HSV color space

        non_uni = 0

        lbp = feature.local_binary_pattern(temp_img, numPoints, radius, method='uniform') ## get uniform lbp
        lbp2 = feature.local_binary_pattern(temp_img, numPoints, radius)  ## Get non uniform LBP

        # Map hue from 0-180 between 0-360                    # Map sat from 0-255 between 0-100
        hue, sat = hsv_img[:, :, 0].astype(np.float16) * 2, hsv_img[:, :, 1].astype(np.float16) * 0.39215686274509803

        for jj in range(temp_img.shape[1]):
            for ii in range(temp_img.shape[0]):
                swh_hist[int(hue[ii][jj] * slope)] += sat[ii][jj]  ## Create SWH Histogram for the individual grid
                if not uniformity(lbp2[ii][jj]):
                    non_uni += 1 ## Count non uni LBP pixels in the grid

        hsv_feature_vect = np.append(hsv_feature_vect, swh_hist)

        hist, _ = np.histogram(lbp, bins=31)
        hist = np.append(hist, non_uni) / norm_factor

        blockFeatures.append(hist)

    feature_vect = list(np.concatenate(blockFeatures))
    hsv_feature_vect = np.array([hsv_feature_vect]) / (norm_factor)
    hsv_feature_vect = list(np.concatenate(hsv_feature_vect))
    features = np.array(np.append(feature_vect, hsv_feature_vect))
    return (np.around(features, decimals=3))

def classify_gender(face_features):

    prediction = gender_classifier.predict(face_features.reshape(1,-1))

    return prediction
```

How I use those functions:

```py
import cv2, argparse
import utils_gender


ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", required=True,
    help="path to the video to be processed")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

image = cv2.imread(args["image"])

head_features = utils_gender.feature_extractor(image)

gender = utils_gender.classify_gender(head_features)

print(gender)
```

The drive link below contains the model, dataset, and the notebook that I used through all the stuff I mentioned.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Sc5ANjomztd6quqqkAx4HMLEXAHyhZcf

Outputs should be varying between male and female but only output I get in every case is female.

Answer (score 0):

You should provide a description of how the model was trained.

If you used the 20% "test" data actually as a validation set, that would indicate that your model might not have learned anything and is just overfitting.